# Fastest way to Sort an algo in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am preparing for Codility. And I need to find out what is the fastest way to find an array with big values and many entries?

Is inbuilt python sort is the fastest or do i need to implement some other sort method?

Comment: It's not clear what it means to sort an algo[rithm] or to find an array. Can you rephrase the question so that it makes more sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your data is already in Python, the Python's [sort](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) is likely the fastest way to go.  It uses the [Timsort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) which performs well on random data and very well on partially ordered data.

If you only need the largest items, use [heapq.nlargest](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest).

Comment: heapq.nlargest and heapq.nsmallest: "The latter two functions perform best for smaller values of n. For larger values, it is more efficient to use the sorted() function. Also, when n==1, it is more efficient to use the built-in min() and max() functions."

Answer (score 2):

The impression I get from the [codility.com](http://codility.com/) job interview site is that a correct solution, provided quickly, is a lot more important than a harder-to-debug (but possibly more efficient) solution. In that environment, use Python's built-in sort, Timsort, which is reasonably efficient at sorting big arrays with big numbers, is stable, and sorts in place.

Comment: Can you pls tell me what all do I need to prepare for the codility test?

Comment: I don't know what is needed, but I based my comment on two sentences from the website:  "Codility saves time of software talent recruiters by filtering out job candidates who cannot write
correct programs.  Codility administers short programming tests
and checks whether solutions are rock solid."  Both sentences emphasize program correctness.  The second also suggests avoiding corner case problems; which generally are less likely to occur with heavily-used library routines.

Comment: @jwpat7: When you are being tested on Codility, you have time limit, but your solution is being assigned a complexity note. And it seems that very efficient, working, but "hard to understand" solution, is a lot better idea than simple, but quick one. What I can see from the demo prepared for the recruiters, Codility gives you time limit, allows recruiter to see your code, but the most important is script's durability and speed. The goal is that script returns the result as fast as possible, and for every possible input.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
list.sort()
```

would be the simplest method of sorting a list in place, if you don't mind losing the original list you should use this method.

using

```
sorted()
```

will return a new list, making it less efficient than `list.sort()` but if you need to keep the original list this is the way to do it.